# Ist it okay hp-setup asks me for root privileges during plugin install?

Tags: 18.04, printing, hplip

While running *hp-setup* from the *hplip* package, a dialog asks me to enter root/superuser password in order to install a downloaded plugin. Is that ok and part of the overall procedure? As I understand it, hplip is userspace...

Comment: Yes, provided that script hasn't been tampered with and the source is authentic!

Comment: Thanks, George. So I made sure it is authentic by tracking down the source of _hp-setup_, which is a symlink in the _hplip_ package, pointing to a script _setup.py_ from _hplip-data_ - downloaded the deb package manually, looked into the md5sums file from control, checked it against md5sum of _setup.py_ on my system _/usr/share/hplip/setup.py_ and they match. All good.

Comment: Then you good to go!